# Incorporating a grayscale TIFF as alpha channel in another TIFF with ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, photoshop, layer, alpha, tiff

When I scan negatives Sane provides 16-bit grayscale files containing infrared information along with the 48-bit RGB files that contain the image information.

Is there any way to combine these two files using ImageMagick in order to obtain a 64-bit RGBA TIFF file whose Alpha channel (infrared) is somehow recognized in Photoshop? Photoshop may detect it as transparency, separate layer or even outright Alpha channel. All these are fine by me.

I haven't been able to obtain much following numerous ImageMagick tutorials on the internet. All TIFFs I get are devoid of transparency information. Libtiff's `tiff2rgba` does not seem to be of much help either.

My ImageMagick version information:

```
$ convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.8-6 Q16 x86_64 2014-02-17 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2014 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC
Delegates: bzlib fftw fontconfig freetype jng jpeg lcms lzma png tiff webp x xml zlib
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% certain I have got your filetypes and needs exactly understood, but if I create a red square `TIFF` like this:

```
convert -size 512x512 xc:red rgb.tiff
```

[image]

and a synthetic (faked) greysale gradient to represent your IR image, like this:

```
convert -size 512x512 -colorspace gray gradient:\#000000-\#ffffff ir.tiff
```

[image]

I can combine them using the IR as opacity like this:

```
convert rgb.tiff ir.tiff -compose copyopacity -composite out.tiff
```

to give this, which at least my version of Photoshop CC 2014 understands.

By the way. it seems equally happy creating a Photoshop `PSD` format directly:

```
convert rgb.tiff ir.tiff -compose copyopacity -composite out.psd
```

[image]

Comment: This is great. The issue was in the order of the commands. Now this one works perfectly. One question, though: For a single film strip scanned a an effective 1200 ppi resolution I normally have 80-90 MB of color information and 20-30 megabytes of IR information. The file created using this method is around 250-260 MB large (for both PSD and TIFF outputs). This is more than two times the size of the two original files together! Is there any specific reason for that?

Comment: Try adding `-compress lzw` just before the output filename and let me know if that helps.